# Default model & measurement units in Autodesk Forge Viewer3D

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any way to globally set measure units and precision in Viewer3D? We do following steps after extension is loaded:

```
onExtensionLoaded(e) {
    if (e.extensionId === 'Autodesk.Measure') {
        const ext = this.viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure');
        ext.snapper.setSnapToPixel(true);
        ext.sharedMeasureConfig.units = 'm';
        ext.sharedMeasureConfig.precision = 3;
        ext.measureTool.setUnits('m');
    }
    ...
}
```

We are not successful with predefining measure unit in **Calibration dialog** to meters. Also call:

```
ext.calibrationTool.getCurrentUnits();
```

Returns inches.

After investigation we found this magic line of code, where the zero index in combobox is selected:

```
CalibrationPanel.js:

this.unitList = new avp.OptionDropDown("Unit type", this.tbody, unitNames, 0, null, { paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 15});
```

We have not found any way to globally set units in Viewer3D. Are we missing anything?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no global way to obtain the info. you wanted since the measure tool now is a viewer extension. So, please use the following functions instead:

- For units: `ext.getUnits()`
- For precision: `ext.getPrecision()`

Comment: Thanks, but our main problem is that we can not set default unit 'm' in calibration dialog.

Comment: Sorry, I got no luck to reproduce this issue on v7.*. Could you consider providing more details about how this happened?  A screencast is better. After running the same codes you mentioned, my calibration dialog's units changed to `m` as expected.

Comment: If it cannot be posted publicly, please send it to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com, thanks! Note. please any personal or confidential information from anything you want to share with us before sending it.